# Android - does Bundle.getParcelableArraylist return a copy of the value of the reference?

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

So in my `MainActivity` I initialize an `ArrayList` and pass it to a `Fragment` through `Bundle`.

I then modify this `ArrayList` in `Fragment`. Then, when I close/pause the app, I save my `ArrayList` in `MainActivity` - this reflects the change made in `Fragment`, which gives me a sense that `Bundle` is passing the value of the reference, not a copy of the raw data.

Now, say I do the first two steps that were stated above - initialize an `ArrayList` and pass it to a `Fragment` through `Bundle`, then modify this `ArrayList` in `Fragment`.

When I pause the app (which again, saved my `ArrayList` in `MainActivity`) so that it's in the background, sometimes, while still inside a `Fragment`, the `MainActivity` gets destroyed. When I open the app again, the saved ArrayList is initialized, but this time, I do not pass it into my `Fragment` because there is still an instance of it available.

**Now this is where I'm confused** - when the `Fragment` is re-opened, it contains the changes that were made, even though this time around, I did not pass the loaded `ArrayList` into the `Fragment`.

So does this mean `Bundle` passes a value of the reference that persists even though the `Fragments` and `Activity` go through its destroy phases?.

To give more clarity, here is the `onCreate` of my `MainActivity`:

```
private ArrayList<Course> courses;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textViewToolbarTitle);
    showHideToolbarListener = new ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener(toolbar);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationInfo().name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    courses = loadData();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putParcelableArrayList("courses", courses);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }


}
```

and here is the `onCreateView` of my `MainFragment`:

```
private ArrayList<Course> courses;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    courses = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("courses");
    ...
}
```

Comment: nope.  passing data via a bundle is passing by value not reference.

Comment: if that's the case, how am I able to modify the data in my Fragments but still save the changes in the onStop of my Activity?

Comment: @SteelBytes Nope. Sometimes it's passed directly if you pass from fragment to fragment. Not the case if its activity to fragment